# How to make a marker adjust its size based on zoom level Google Maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to follow the behavior of Google Maps, wherein the markers of certain landmark appear small in a lower zoom level, but bigger on a higher level. I was already able to make a custom marker disappear by zoom level, now I want to make its size adjust relevant to the zoom level. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. Android Newbie here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `onCameraChange` instead of calling `setVisible`, call `setIcon` with different `BitmapDescriptor` depending on zoom level.