# How to adjust markers icon size according to the zoom level on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, zooming, google-maps-markers

I'm adding several markers on my maps and i want that they adjust their icon size while zooming-in or zooming-out. How to do that?

This is my code:

```
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if (map!=null) {
            map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
            map.setTrafficEnabled(true);
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(defaultLatLng, zoomLevel));

            this.addMarkers(new MarkerOptions());
```

This is my addMarkers method:

```
public void addMarkers(MarkerOptions mo) {
    db = new Database(this);
    SQLiteDatabase dbRead = db.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {"title", "addr", "lat", "lon"};
    Cursor result = dbRead.query("people", columns, null, null, null, null, null);

while(result.moveToNext()){
    String person = result.getString(0);
    String address = result.getString(1);
    float lat = result.getFloat(2);
    float lon = result.getFloat(3);

    map.addMarker(mo.position(new LatLng(lat, lon))
            .title(person)
            .snippet(address)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));;
}
```

}

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15685465/3168859)

Comment: OR this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19156367/3168859)